# How do I see outgoing changes with fossil

Tags: fossil

With veracity and mercurial you can do a "outgoing" command to see what changes would be pushed to the server. How can I do that with fossil?

Answer (score 2):

Fossil does not have an equivalent to Mercurial's `hg incoming` or `hg outgoing` (cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software#Advanced_commands) for lack of a better source, and from personal experience).  While that is somewhat annoying, I've not yet come across any way to simulate it via a script or something of the like.

Long story short:  You cannot, full stop.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want something like:

`fossil changes` to report on the edit status of all files in current checkout, and possibly `fossil diff` to see the details of the changes that you are about to commit and/or to push.

Remember that fossil has "autosync" turned on by default, so unless you turn that off, any commit you make locally will also go to your server, in case you have set up version with a central server.